# Select box need Focus in first element of the search field (multiselect)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

> This is my select Box Now its working fine, But I want the first element in search to be **focus**, Any idea will appreciate

[image]

```
      $('.newmultiselect').multiselect({
          enableFiltering: true,
          filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
          enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering : true,
          includeSelectAllOption: false,
          onChange: function(element, checked) {
            var selectID = $(element).parent().attr('id');
            $("#"+selectID).valid();
          }
      });
      searchMultiselect();
```

**My state field Div**

```
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <div class="form-group">
                <p>State<span class="notice-txt">*</span></p>
                  <select class="form-control validrmvcls newmultiselect" id="state" name="state">
                   <option value="">--Select--</option>
                     @foreach($states as $st)
                      <option value="{{$st['state_prefix']}}">{{$st['state_prefix']}}</option>
                     @endforeach
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css first child property, and for selecting default you can pass the value of first option in your result dataSet.

Comment: But I need in jquery, That means like enableFiltering, filterPlaceholder Like that

Comment: You can use css in jquery too, by using .addClass method to any element

Comment: Yeah I know Bro, But I am asking is there any predefined function in jquery multiselect

Comment: If its No, Surely i will follow your steps

Comment: Check focus-selector see if it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `onDropdownShown` callback and focus on your input.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to focus on input but first element, just do it like this:

```js
onDropdownShown : function() {
    $('li:visible:not(.multiselect-filter)').eq(0).focus();
}
```

Comment: But still facing same issue

Comment: While i am inspecting the search result i am getting this one
 <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio"><input value="Southeast" type="radio"> Southeast</label></a></li>

Comment: What issue? Check in devtools class of this input maybe it is different than `.multiselect-filter-hidden`

Comment: Yeah i already checked that sir. this is the class  <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="radio"><input value="Southeast" type="radio"> Southeast</label></a></li>

Comment: No, this is just next element. I'm talking about the input.

Comment: wait sir, let me post my answer

Comment: sir sorry to disturb you, please have a look in my answer sir

Comment: @SivaGanesh Try now

Comment: Sir solution ??.

Comment: @SivaGanesh Just try edited answer. You can see, that I changed class name `.multiselect-filter-hidden` to `.multiselect-filter input`

Comment: sir its still focusing on my input, I need my focus in search result. that means i need my focus in southeast not in my search input

Comment: @SivaGanesh ok, you should start with that :) Try now edited answer

Comment: Sorry to say sir, still same result

Answer (score 0):

**Krzysztof Janiszewski** please have a look

[image]