# Keycode alerting undefined in jquery onDropdownShown. I am not sure where i done the mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

My keycode is always alerting `undefined`. Please tell me guys if I've made any mistake

```
 $('.newmultiselect').multiselect({
      enableFiltering: true,
      filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering : true,
      includeSelectAllOption: false,
      onChange: function(element, checked) {
        var selectID = $(element).parent().attr('id');
        $("#"+selectID).valid();
      },    
      onDropdownShown : function(event) {
        $('.newmultiselect').parent().find(".multiselect-search").on('keyup', function(){ 
             if (event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 13) {
                alert('0000');
             } 
            alert(event.keyCode);
            $('.multiselect-filter-hidden').focus();
        });
      }
  });
```

Comment: It's because there is no `event` variable defined in the `keyup` handler function. Did you put the argument in the wrong place - ie. in the outer `onDropdownShown` event handler?

Comment: Also, be very wary of adding event handlers within event handlers, as you're duplicating them each time. I'd suggest using a delegated event handler for the `keyup` event

Comment: can you please post as a answer, Dont mistake me

Comment: Sure, I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you've specified the event argument on the outer `onDropdownShown` event handler instead of the inner `keyup` event handler, where you're actually intending to use it.

Also note that nesting event handlers is not a good idea, as you're duplicating the inner handler every time the outer one executes. To fix this, change the `keyup` handler to use the delegated pattern. Try this:

```js
$('.newmultiselect').multiselect({
  enableFiltering: true,
  filterPlaceholder: 'Search',
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  includeSelectAllOption: false,
  onChange: function(element, checked) {
    var selectID = $(element).parent().attr('id');
    $("#" + selectID).valid();
  }
});

$(document).on('keyup', ".multiselect-search", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert('0000');
  }
  alert(event.keyCode);
  $('.multiselect-filter-hidden').focus();
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461105/select-box-need-focus-in-first-element-of-the-search-field-multiselect-than Please have a look sir

Answer (score 1):

It is because you use `event` variable of `onDropdownShown` callback.

You should use `event` variable in `keyup` event instead

```
onDropdownShown : function() {
  $('.newmultiselect').parent().find(".multiselect-search").on('keyup', function(event) { 
       if (event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 13) {
          alert('0000');
       } 
      alert(event.keyCode);
      $('.multiselect-filter-hidden').focus();
  });
}
```

Comment: One more help, Can you suggest me any idea

Comment: @SivaGanesh I don't understand. What would you like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461105/select-box-need-focus-in-first-element-of-the-search-field-multiselect-than. Please take a look, and give me a solution if its possible